# Is it sinful to give bribe to have the inaffordable taxes reduced?

Tags: halal-haram, riba

We have two homes and we have rented them. The govt has now increased property taxes greatly. The property tax of two houses sum up to around sixty-thousand.

I am a salaried person my father died, and the rents and my salary are the only source of our income. Those taxes are two much for us to afford.

An official from the tax department asked me for some bribe money to have those taxes reduced.

Should I give him? And would I be equally responsible in that sin provided the act is sinful?

Comment: I don't know your financial status. Living is getting hard in Pakistan (I assume you are from the country). But *Qana'at* is a precious gift, if one can adopt.

Comment: Duplicate http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/916/does-islam-permit-tax-evasion

Answer (score 1):

Okay why it should not be sinful?
Will you give bribe in public? or in private?
Will you tell everyone you gave bribe to not pay unaffordable taxes?

Now you will never tell any one. You will feel ashamed while telling this to any one.

So the deeds which we want to keep private and do in private are almost our bad deeds. So they are counted as sin.

When prophets has nothing to eat and wear. Did they stole anything or Did they went for some sinful way to get these things for them as these were their basic needs and islam states first care about your health then anything else. So why they didnt?

Answer (score 0):

Islam is about being honest and truthful. If we truly love our prophet and not just claim it, we will do what he did.

He was known as the honest. There were couple of occasions when Islam came, they said had anyone else said it, we would not have believed it. Since it is him, we cannot disbelieve it.

Islam is about telling the truth even if that is something that goes against you.

If you truly fear God, then you wont avoid taxes.

Bribery whether private or public the prophet said: 
الراشي والمرتشي في النار
That who bribes and that who takes bribe they will both go to hell.