# What is the Islamic Judgment of paying taxes from the US

Tags: fatwa

Is it Haram to pay taxes for America for the Muslims who live in there , and is it "Tawlli" [Helping a kaft against Muslims ]

Comment: can we generalize this question to all non Muslim states or you really want to ask about US?

Comment: Is it your position, then, that the US is at war with "Islam"? Because I don't think that is how the US sees it. It is, openly, combating some terrorist groups who happen to *be* Muslims, but that is not the same thing. For other examples, look at Mali or the recent Siege at the refinery in the Sahara. It is not unreasonable to want to remove such obvious threats, and that does not mean it is "anti-Islamic" to do so. IMO.

Comment: Are you yourself living in the US? Did you go there voluntarily or did someone force you to live there? Do you have a job, or are you refusing to accept money from the infidel?

Answer (score 1):

From my POV there are general aspects regarding paying taxes in islam which apply to non-islamic countries as well - see [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/921/965) for a very good explanation. Basically as long as there is no direct sin involved a muslim is obliged to follow the laws/rules of the country he is living in and on the other hand the ruler must not take taxes by force.

Other aspects to take into consideration can be found [here](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84560) - it states that to ward off injustice it is allowed to lie and if a country is at war with muslim it is haram to pay taxes to that country.  Although I would be **very cautious on applying this without a real fatwa regarding you specific case**...

Comment: Are you sunni ?

Comment: @user7322 yes...

Comment: I already read this before , but I am asking about the judgment of A muslim paying taxes for America,,, does someone become helping against Muslims

Comment: @user7322 2 necessary things are missing to give you a direct answer... first: in your question there are by far not enough details, second: the one giving you a really robust answer will need to be someone having the right to give a binding fatwa... neither is the case... thus I don't see how you will get an answer on the level you demand...

Comment: @Yahia you need to expand on your answer. At least extract what the link says.

Comment: I sent a fatwa , for the mufti of the u.s , so let's wait til he gives me answer

Comment: @user7322 that is very good... please add the response when you receive it so others can benefit too from it.

Comment: I asked a similar question here:
https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/77278/what-are-different-viewpoints-on-supporting-immoral-wars-through-paying-taxes
and here for christianity:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39648/what-is-an-overview-of-different-stances-on-whether-and-why-it-is-a-sin-to-pay-t