# What are different viewpoints on supporting immoral wars through paying taxes?

Tags: sin, war, sects

What are some viewpoints on whether it is considered a sin, or not allowed under Islamic law, to pay taxes which go towards the support of wars of aggression, or wars considered immoral by yourself or your interpretation of your religion?

For example, if you consider the "wars" the United States has conducted in Libya, Syria, Iraq, etc to be immoral wars of aggression, what are some viewpoints held by Islamic institutions or sects on whether you should pay taxes to a government conducting such wars?

I see a related question is here: [What is the Islamic Judgment of paying taxes from the US](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7098/what-is-the-islamic-judgment-of-paying-taxes-from-the-us)  however I am not asking about specific terminology such as Fatwa and Tawlli, just about general viewpoints which may or may not fit in with that terminology.

I asked a similar question in the Christian stack exchange here and received an answer which covered various movements and sects: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/39648/what-is-an-overview-of-different-stances-on-whether-and-why-it-is-a-sin-to-pay-t

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean a difference 
of viewpoint as "yes/ no" or the viewpoint of 4 Sunni madhabs, or the viewpoint of Shiites madhabs.

Comment: I meant for the viewpoint of the groups anyone would like to share, whether they be large and established institutions or individual scholars. So for example, someone could say "Most Islamic institutions consider .... to be ..., but the ... consider it to be ..."

Answer (score 2):

It is disliked for a muslim to reside in a non muslim country, and forbidden if the muslim would face difficulty practicing their religion (Islam). However it is encouraged if done for "Dawah".

If a Muslim enters a non-muslim country, he must adhere to the conditions that have been set forth, as Allah says:

> O you who believe! Fulfill (your) obligations
>
> [al-Maa'idah 5:1]

Hence tax evasion is not permissible for any Muslim unless there is a genuine reason such as unfair tax, unavailing taxes, sinful use of tax or state rivalry/oppression with Muslim/Islam.

A Muslim should not channel immoral, anti-islam wars because it forbidden to deal with those who fight/fought you on religion.

> Allah does not forbid you to deal justly and kindly with those who fought not against you on account of religion and did not drive you out of your homes. Verily, Allaah loves those who deal with equity. [al-Mumtahinah 60:8]

So if any nation/state opposes others (Muslim) based upon religion (Islam), the Muslim should not support them by paying taxes. Also further cleared by this fatwa from [Islamweb](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.islamweb.net/amp/en/fatwa/84560/):

> But, if such a state is at war with Muslims, then it is forbidden to pay taxes to it.